# How to initiate a DateEdit with a random date

Tags: c#, wpf, date

Im new in WPF and c# language, And I appreciate if you can help me.

I have two DateEdit controls  and a GridControl.

I want to assign a random date in first Date edit, and the 2'nd DateEdit  should be assigned with a year diferrence and from this date.

The same dates should be assigned to the GridControl.

The code is:

```
    private void mTxtDateEditFchIni_EditValueChanged(object sender, EditValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        mTxtDateEditFchFin.Text = fecha.ToString();

    }
```

mTxtDateEditfchIni is the first text edit with the event editvalue

I want a to put a date in first any date and automatically the 2nd date ( mTxtDateEditFchFin.Text) put a year of diferrence of first dateedit

Comment: Please share what you have tried. This will help people to be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Ok,Erick andres you know speak Spanish?

Comment: Not all code, Like and advanced opinion of all you guys please, Like a clue for guide me please

Comment: I do speak Spanish, but I meant you should post your code. Questions on StackOverflow need to stick to English.

Comment: Ok, I will post the code :)

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel and handle all that at the ViewModel level and have your UI bound to that data.

Comment: Ok the post is already edit please read it and try to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do that in WPF (with DevExpress):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.DateRangeGridSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
        xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
        Title="DateRangeGridSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Label Content="Start Date:"/>
            <dxe:DateEdit EditValue="{Binding FocusedRow.StartDate, ElementName=Table}"/>
            <Label Content="End Date:"/>
            <dxe:DateEdit EditValue="{Binding FocusedRow.EndDate, ElementName=Table}"/>
            <Button Content="New" Click="NewRow" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView x:Name="Table" ShowGroupPanel="False"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="StartDate"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="EndDate"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class DateRangeGridSample : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DateRange> Data { get; set; }

    public DateRangeGridSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = Data = new ObservableCollection<DateRange>();
    }

    private void NewRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Data.Add(new DateRange() {StartDate = DateTime.Today, EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1)});
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class DateRange: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private DateTime _endDate;

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
        }
    }

    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return _endDate; }
        set
        {
            _endDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- You don't (normally) handle any events in WPF (except for the Button Click, which could also be replaced by a [Command](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)
- Everything is done via [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). You really need to learn that if you're using WPF.
- WPF Rocks. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I really appreciate that. But my properties and almost all stuff are diferrents but i really appreciate that.(Y)

Comment: @aragongiuseppe how is it different? Would you like to post your current code?

Comment: @aragongiuseppe check my Stackoverflow profile. My email address is there.

Comment: DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            mTxtDateEditFchFin.Text = fecha.ToString();
            mpxEnabledCtls(clsAppEnum.mexAccFrm.mvxAddNew);
            mDetalle_grdctl.View.IsEnabled = true;
            mDetalle_grctlvie.NewItemRowPosition =   NewItemRowPosition.Bottom;
             mDetalle_grctlvie.MoveLastRow();
                 mDetalle_grdctl.View.MoveLastRow();
                            mDetalle_grdctl.View.AllowEditing = true;
                            movar_isupdatemod = false;
                            mDetalle_grdctl.CurrentItem = fecha;
        }

Comment: @aragongiuseppe You need to refactor that code and put all these properties in a ViewModel, instead of using code behind.

Comment: my facebook is Aragon Giuseppe, Please add me, How can i refactor the code and put that code in ViewModel?